# Flutter docs are very confusing, what's the use of SliverOverlapAbsorber and SliverOverlapInjector?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html#widgets.NestedScrollView.1) from flutter official docs. Here is the minimal code:

```
List<String> _tabs = ["Tab1", "Tab2"];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: _tabs.length,
    child: Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            // 1/2 remove this widget and only use SliverAppBar
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
              child: SliverAppBar(
                title: const Text('Books'),
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 150.0,
                bottom: TabBar(tabs: _tabs.map((name) => Tab(text: name)).toList()),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: _tabs.map((String name) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return CustomScrollView(
                  key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    // 2/2 remove this widget
                    SliverOverlapInjector(handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)),
                    SliverFixedExtentList(
                      itemExtent: 48.0,
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')),
                        childCount: 30,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Problem:**

As you can see if I remove `SliverOverlapAbsorber` along with `SliverOverlapInjector` in above code, I don't see any change in the output, what's the use of having it? Docs say

> SliverOverlapInjector: This widget takes the overlapping behavior of the SliverAppBar, and redirects it to the SliverOverlapInjector below. If it is missing, then it is possible for the nested "inner" scroll view below to end up under the SliverAppBar even when the inner scroll view thinks it has not been scrolled. This is not necessary if the "headerSliverBuilder" only builds widgets that do not overlap the next sliver.

Can anyone explain what does it mean and what's the use of having `SliverOverlapInjector` and `SliverOverlapInjector`

Answer (score 6):

I use it in `NestedScrollView`

```
NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
    SliverOverlapAbsorber(
      handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
      sliver: SliverAppBar()
  ],
  body: ...
)
```

Without it everything in your body will go under appbar.

Check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html

It's said there

```
SliverOverlapAbsorber(
  // This widget takes the overlapping behavior of the SliverAppBar,
  // and redirects it to the SliverOverlapInjector below. If it is
  // missing, then it is possible for the nested "inner" scroll view
  // below to end up under the SliverAppBar even when the inner
  // scroll view thinks it has not been scrolled.
  // This is not necessary if the "headerSliverBuilder" only builds
  // widgets that do not overlap the next sliver.
  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
```